# My replacement ignition key doesn't work the doors on my Peugot 308

Tags: ignition, key, door, peugeot-308

I had my keys replaced for a Peugot 308, one with a remote and one as a manual key after I lost the original. Both keys work as ignition keys and the remote fob locks as it should but neither key will turn the door locks. I'm worried in case the fob fails to work when the doors are locked, I live in a remote area with dead spots for mobiles! Is there anything I can try myself or will I have to approach Peugot or an agent to have a separate door key cut?

Comment: If neither new key turns the door locks, then either the keys were mis-cut and don't match the door lock cylinders, or both door lock cylinders are in some manner worn or defective or broken. You need a locksmith.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The other thought which David didn't state is, if the way you got new keys was with a new ignition cylinder (and the keys), then the door cylinders might not have been changed out at the same time. If so, they'd work for your old keys, but not the new ones.

Comment: Yes, Paulster2 is right: I assumed the door lock cylinders were original.

Comment: If this is a remote fob with a pull-out emergency key then you need to switch the pull-out key from your old fob to your new fob.